# Laravel Horizon not processing queues

Tags: php, laravel, laravel-horizon

Since I've upgraded my Laravel application from 5.4 to 5.5 and added Laravel Horizon, my queue isn't working anymore. Here is the old situation which worked:

The driver I used was Beanstalkd and Supervisord for monitoring the task and keep it up and running. I ran it using this command:

```
php artisan queue:work --tries=1 --queue=high,medium,low
```

New situation: I've updated the queue driver to Redis. When I take a look at *mydomain.com/horizon*, I see the tasks coming in but not being processed. Running the following command from the terminal doesn't work either:

```
php artisan queue:work --tries=1 --queue=high,medium,low
```

I have 2 queues that are filled, the Redis queue and the Beanstalkd queue. How can I finish the Beanstalkd queue and then process the Horizon queue?

Comment: When you run php artisan queue:work without specifying a connection it'll just use the default connection - im assuming you have separate connection entries for your beanstalk and redis drivers. you can specify the connection with php artisan queue:work beanstalk or php artisan queue:work redis (whatever your connections are called)

Comment: .... the connections should be in config/queue.php

Comment: Have you tried specifying the driver as part of the command? php artisan queue:work redis --queue=whatever

Comment: ... your .env should have the default queue driver ie. QUEUE_DRIVER=redis

Comment: @aarcarr i've tried that. php7 artisan queue:listen beanstalkd --tries=1 --queue=high,medium,low,default but there wasnt any output. i also configured my .env file

Comment: @DaveCarruthers yeah i did that, same as what Aarcarr says

Comment: Your dispatching jobs to one of the queues you listed? for example: MyJob::dispatch($obj)->onConnection('redis')->onQueue('high');

Comment: Are you only doing "php7 artisan queue:listen" on the beanstalk queue ? you need to do php7 artisan queue:work too

Answer (score 7):

I figured out that the command `artisan down` will block the queue workers :) So after running artisan up everything works good... *I think its time for the weekend :P*

Comment: Its awesome figuring stuff out :)

Comment: tick your answer !!

Comment: I cant do that yet... I need to wait 2 days before i can :(

Comment: Thanks for the help btw!

Comment: God damn it! Two hours wasted :( . I guess I deserve this for working the weekend :D.

Thanks for mentioning this.